# InAppBrowser on Android

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser, cordova-3

*UPDATE: The method below now works.*

Create project:

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
cd hello
cordova platform add android
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git
cordova build
```

Then create a new project from existing source in Eclipe (Android Developer Tools).

Just add the sample code from the documentation.

HTML:

```
<a onclick="testIAB();" style="display: block; width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: yellow;">Test IAB</a>
```

JS:

```
function testIAB() {
     var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are removing the plugin with

```
cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.core.inappbrowser
```

Comment: D'oh, of course. Does this have effect when I'm adding the plugin manually to config.xml?